# How to prevent file loaded in memory entirely while checking its size using CommonsMultipartFile ? (java, spring)

Tags: java, file-upload, spring-mvc

I have a form object that is being filled correctly automagically by Spring. Within this form object I have a field:

```
CommonsMultipartFile file;
```

The user can upload a file and the form object contains the file properly. All is good. However, I want to make sure a user cannot upload files larger than 2 MB. I have made a check and also that works.

The problem: When I upload a very large file (say 500MB), I will end up with such a large file in memory in my form object (I assume this). Is there any way to prevent this? Like, is there any way to check the file size with a validator, but without the need to load up the entire file before checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `CommonsMultipartResolver`, then you can use its `maxUploadSize` property to limit this. See [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-resolver) for an example.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like if i specify that bean Spring should detect that and simply use that property. Will try it out right now and let you know the result.

Comment: Ok. It works! However, now the error page is a 500 status page which I did not want. I can also not find anything about that in the Spring documentation. Thanks though, this part of the riddle is solved

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch that MaxUploadSizeExceededException, I use the following :

In the controller, you should implement the HandlerExceptionResolver interface.

Then, implement the resolveException method :

```
// Catch file too big exception
@Override
public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception) {
    if (exception instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException) {
        // Do something with exception here
    }       

    // Goes back to original view here
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("uploadFile", new UploadFile());
    return new ModelAndView(associatedView,model);
}
```